# Why does WaitForSingleObject(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, INFINITE) block?

Tags: windows, winapi, multithreading, synchronization, waitforsingleobject

Why does

```
HANDLE mutexHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
WaitForSingleObject(mutexHandle, INFINITE);
```

block? It does not return with an error message. Checking the handle for `INVALID_HANDLE` would be stupid for a mutex as I would need a mutex for accessing the mutex handle...

BTW: It does return with `WAIT_FAILED` if the handle was closed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/02/82639.aspx:

> Fourth, you have to be particularly careful with the `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` value: By coincidence, the value `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` happens to be numerically equal to the pseudohandle returned by `GetCurrentProcess()`. Many kernel functions accept pseudohandles, so if if you mess up and accidentally call, say, `WaitForSingleObject` on a failed `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` handle, you will actually end up waiting on your own process. This wait will, of course, never complete, because a process is signalled when it exits, so you ended up waiting for yourself.

Comment: I think I feel sick now... So I need to keep the old handle around and signal validity with a separate flag. Why doesn't the documentation say so...

Comment: I'd wrap `WaitForSingleObject` and return `WAIT_FAILED` for `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, it will probably take less coding.